# Powering up an ESP32 with IO extender (MCP23017) and two of 8 channel relays from an external 5 V, 10 A power supply

Tags: power-supply, esp8266, esp32

I'm working on a project that needs an **ESP32 board**, **IO extender (MCP23017)**, **two of 8 channel relays** and some **sensors**, I've powered up all of the parts from a stable **5 V, 10 A power supply** as shown in this block diagram:

[image: the block diagram of the parts]

Added: More detailed wiring diagram:

[image: diagram showing external connections to the ESP32 board]

After connecting all the parts to the external power supply, the ESP32 gets too hot and then it burns after 10 seconds.

Could you please correct my connections, if there are any mistakes?

The sensors are:

- **2 DHT22**
- **2 MQ135**
- **2 Magnetic switches**
- **Ultrasonic**

Thanks for your time.

---

Update: The connections were correct. I've just added voltage dividers and it worked correctly.

[image: diagram showing external connections to the ESP32 board, with added voltage-dividers]

Comment: That diagram does not tell us anything. The  ESP32 can get hot if you have connected it wrong or if one or more outputs are active and shortened. Neither of those can we see from your diagram. What I am also worried about is your question *"Does the power supply provide too much current?"* which tells me you are missing fundamental knowledge about electronics but still started a complex project.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm not a beginner in electronics, but I faced this power issue and the wiring concept is like in the diagram, I know electronics draw the needed current from the power supply, not all the 10Amps as in short circuit. I just need a correction, if you don't mind.

Comment: Dear hassan, I repeat myself: nobody can help you based on that diagram. That diagram shows how things **should** have been connected up and maybe they are. But if there are no mistakes your ESP32 would not get hot. You tell me it is getting hot, thus somewhere there is misstake and we can't point it out to you based on the diagram.

Comment: As far as I can tell, ESP32 modules are intended operate on 3.3V, not 5V.  What's the input voltage for your ESP32 module?

Comment: Right, 3.3v but I'm powering it up through its v5(USB) pin so the input is 5.1v, it works with no problem if there's nothing connected to it.

Comment: Mr @Oldfart, I've added the connection diagram to the post. Could you take a look at the diagram if you have time, please? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ESP32 runs of 3.3V (I found a schematic which I hope is the correct one).

I do not have schematics of the other parts but I notice that everything runs of 5V. 
I suggest you check:

1. If the I/O of all connected ports are 3V3. 
   or
2. If the ESP32 has 5V tolerant ports.

If not you are connecting 5V I/O ports to a 3V3 processor. That might explain why it gets hot.

A more dangerous way is to connect things one-by-one and check which one makes it get hot. (I would normally not recommended that but it is a quick-and-dirty way to narrow done where the problem is)